# Understanding JavaScript Objects and its properties

Tags: javascript

I run into this piece of code while learning Redux. I am sure that the funtion returning an object and the object has `type`, `id`, `text` properties. I know that `type` equal to `ADD_TODO` and `id` equal to `nextTodoId++`. But I have no idea about the last property. Does it mean that `text: text` ?

```
export const addTodo = text => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})
```

Comment: _"Does it mean that `text: text`"_ <- yes!

Comment: It's a new ES6 feature, if your key and value are same you don't have to repeat it, You can read more about it here http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/